# How to make a button appear pressed when it is not?

Tags: android

I have a button that plays a sound clip when it is pressed.  I would like the button to appear pressed during the duration of the sound clip.  By that, I mean that I would like the button to take on the default pressed-button appearance while the sound is playing.  How can I implement this?  I have tried using a number of things in the onClickListener (such as setSelected, requestFocus, etc), but none of those do the trick.  I have also tried changing the onClickListener to an onTouchListener, again with no dice.  Am I wrong in assuming that there must be a way to simply set the button image to appear pressed? (BTW, the button object is of type Button, not ImageButton).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: change the background of button to pressed state inside `onClickListener()`

Answer (score 1):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716686/android-set-imagebutton-as-toggle) question. It details a couple of different ways this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup 'selector' drawables and let android take care of this for you.