# single Imagebutton use as start-stop-start

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

In my android project i have taken 2 image button(start and stop).
when i pressed START IMAGE BUTTON then it converted to STOP IMAGE BUTTON BUT again when i pressed STOP IMAGE BUTTON it does not converted into START BUTTON.so let me know where is the problem.

```
  mImageButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(
  new OnFocusChangeListener()
  {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (hasFocus==true)
  {
      mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
  }
 else
 {
  mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
 }
  }
 });

 mImageButton.setOnClickListener(
 new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
   }
   });     
 }
}
```

Comment: check www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2fd686/android-buttons-background2/ you should be using `selectors` for what you are trying to do here

Comment: In your onClick, you're setting it to stop.  You need to flip it back to start explicitly if you want that.

Comment: @Naveen yes should be using selectors with ToggleButton for this scenario

Comment: sir ,when i pressed start image button it successfully shows stop image button.this is OK. but when i again pressed that stop image button it does not shows start image button.so what shall i do for reverse action???

Comment: @user2189622 you can simply use a `Boolean` to do what you actually need

Answer (score 1):

In Android `onFocusChange` is called before `onCLick`. Whatever you set in the `onFocusChange` method is ignored, as the `onClick` will be called next, and it changes the image bak to `R.drawable.stop`.

You shouldn't use `onFocusChange` at all for what you are trying to do. Only use onClick instead.

```
private boolean pCurrentlyPlaying = false;

...

mImageButton.setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           int image = pCurrentlyPlaying ? R.drawable.stop : R.drawable.play;
           mImageButton.setImageResource(image);
           pCurrentlyPlaying = !pCurrentlyPlaying ;
       }
    });
```

You can also use the ToggleButton, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2751320/1821029) of how to define it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling the button images in `onFocusChangeListener` instead of `onClickListener`. `ToggleButton` seems to be the right fit for the scenario you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way is to use Selectors

create the following ImgBtnSelector.xml in drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_pressed="true"
     android:drawable="@drawable/custom_info_bubble1" />
    <item 
     android:state_pressed="false"
     android:drawable="@drawable/custom_info_bubble" />
</selector>
```

In our layout xml set Image Button background as this selector.

Here a a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state) on selectors

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code.. May Be Help You.

```
 boolean isStart = true ;
 boolean isStop = false;
 mImageButton.setOnClickListener(
 new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(isStart){
 isStart =false ;
 isStop = true ;
 mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
 }else{
 isStart = true ;
isStop = false;
mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
 }
}
});     
}
}
```

Comment: now it shows warning and error.
isstart-The value of the local variable isStart is not used.
isstart-Cannot refer to a non-final variable isStart inside an inner class defined in a different method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean isStart=true;//This is global

mImageButton.setOnClickListener(
 new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(isStart)
 mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
else
 mImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.start);

isStart=!isStart;
   }
   });     
 }
}
```

This is what you need loose the onfocusChanged part

Comment: isstart-Cannot refer to a non-final variable isStart inside an inner class defined in a different method.

Comment: isstart-The value of the local variable isStart is not used.

Comment: thats why I wrote global variable, you have to declare it outside.

Comment: Thank u sir.but i got errors and warning so can u modify my above java code with proper manner.because i m beginner in android i did not get/understand u about global variable.